# EBNF ESCAPE CHARACTERS

Tags: ebnf

I'm trying to make the grammar expressions for strings for a pseudo-language based on python, and I'm wondering how I can do the following:
The string starts or either ends with " or ' also, it can include any character except / " ' \n. Those characters can only be included when another backslash is leaded, for example:
`'Mark said, \"Boo!\"\n'`(accepted)

Answer (score 0):

I can only test it in [this tester](https://mdkrajnak.github.io/ebnftest/) but the following seems to work for me:

```
escape_sequence = "\\", ( '"' | "'" | "\\" ) ;
string          = ( '"', { escape_sequence | #'[^"]' }, '"' ) | ( "'", { escape_sequence | #"[^']" }, "'" ) ;
```

##### Explanation:

`#` followed by a string matches for a RegEx instead of literally the string's content, at least in mdkrajnak's EBNF tester.