# EBNF - How to define a string that has to start and end with specific character and contains any character?

Tags: ebnf

I'm currently trying to write my own programming language and I start with the syntax definition in EBNF (Extended Backus–Naur form).
I have the problem that I don't know how to define the syntax for a string. I know how to do that in RegEx (`'[^']*'` for single-quoted and `"[^"]*"` for double-quoted strings) but have no clue how to match *every character* in EBNF.
Is there a way to do this or something equivalent without explicitly mentioning each and every of the hundreds of thousands of characters that Unicode has?

## Update

I've found an interesting solution in the [tester I use](https://mdkrajnak.github.io/ebnftest/) which allows me to use RegEx within the EBNF by prepending a string with `#`.
I still can't get it to work properly (because the RegEx is applied to every single character, not the whole string) and I don't know if that syntax is standard EBNF.

My question seems to be similar to [EBNF ESCAPE CHARACTERS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60920893) but not the exact same.

## Update 2

I found a solution that seems to work as intended in the tester I use (I can't be sure if it's universally correct):

```
escape_sequence = "\\", ( '"' | "'" | "\\" ) ;
string          = ( '"', { escape_sequence | #'[^"]' }, '"' ) | ( "'", { escape_sequence | #"[^']" }, "'" ) ;
```